# Laravel ERRO: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: sessions

Tags: php, laravel

[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMGkK.png)

Acabei de baixar o laragon, e em seguida utilizando o composer no terminal eu baixei o laravel. Só que ao tentar rodar e acessar o servidor do laravel que me foi dado, http://127.0.0.1:8000, através do comando "php artisan serve", este erro do anexo aparece! E não estou conseguindo acessar o servidor e nem fazer aplicações de PHP.

Estudei por um video, e quando o cara justamente executa o comando php artisan serve e o dele aparece a página certinha, mas o meu aparece este print anexado.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.